# Is a convex function always twice differentiable?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that f is twice differentiable, that is, its Hessian or second derivative
$\nabla^2f$ exists at each point in dom$f$, which is open. Then f is convex if and
only if dom$f$ is convex and its Hessian is positive semidefinite: for all x ∈ dom$f$,  $\nabla^2f\geq 0$.

Is it possible that a function can be convex but not 2 twice differentiable?

Comment: Try $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is convex but not differentiable!

Comment: Despite these counterexamples, we still have the [Alexandrov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_theorem), which says that a convex function can only fail to have a second derivative on a Lebesgue null set.  So the fact that $|x|$ only fails to have a second derivative at a single point is somehow typical.

Comment: @Josh Keneda: +1 for Alexandrov Theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about $f(x)=\|x\|$? (Euclidean norm)

Answer (score 7):

Convexity doesn't even imply continuity(e.g one can construct a convex function on a closed domain which is nowhere continuous on the boundary).

### Edit

However, *Alexandrov's Theorem* states that a convex function is $\mathcal C^2$ **almost-everywhere**. Now, that's alot of differentiability (depending on what you want to do with it)!

Comment: is it actually $C^2$ almost everywhere or twice differentiable almost everywhere?